# c# Retrieving Inserted ID inside Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have a bunch of inserts which I want to have in a transaction so I can rollback in case of any errors. Now my issue is that for some of the inserts I need the ID of the previous insert. However, doing `var id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();` throws an exception ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object"). If i run `command.ExecuteScalar()` without trying to assign the result the code work perfectly fine. Is it possible to get ID before committing the transaction? If no, what are my alternatives?

My code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionHere")
{
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;

            // Start a local transaction.
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            try
            {                    
                string insertStudent = "INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)" +
                " VALUES (@firstName, @middleName, @lastName)";

                command.CommandText = insertStudent;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", application.FirstName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", application.MiddleName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", application.LastName);

                var id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();//EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

                // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

                // Attempt to roll back the transaction.        
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
}
```

Comment: Replace `int` in the line `var id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();`  with `Int32` Class. ExecuteScalar() returns an Object. This should work

Comment: @vedbhawsar: int is an alias name for Int32..

Comment: @MichaelG You are are right, but using `Int32` saves you when `ExecuteScalar()` returns `null`  as  `Convert.ToInt32(null) = 0`

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that a column in the Students table is setup as an identity column, and that you use SQL Server 2008+.

In that case you need to change your SQL statement to return the inserted identity value like this:

```
  string insertStudent = "INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)" +
            " VALUES (@firstName, @middleName, @lastName);" +
            " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

More information regarding SCOPE_IDENTITY can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know i had to return the inserted identity. However, now i'm getting exception `Specified cast is not valid`. I've tried casting to both (int) and (Int32). What should i be casting to?

Comment: I got it to work using this but also `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` as @vedbhawsar suggested. It wouldn't work any other way I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL syntax to get the inserted ID :

```sql
INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) OUTPUT Inserted.ID ....
```

And then

```
int id = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code

```
  var id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

as:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

This will ensure that even if ExecuteScalar returns null, as result of not selecting anything in stored procedure, countDis will have a value of 0. Because Convert.ToInt32(null) = 0.